# Clone Program Files partition?

Tags: partitioning

My goal is to move the partition containing Program Files to another disk.

Since I can't find any option from the Internet yet, I try to clone the partition to another disk. Is it possible for the OS to re-map the Program Files from source partition to destination partition ?

Note: I'm using EaseUS Partition Master Free Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work even if you are able to copy all the files.  The registry on the "new" system will be missing many entries. It would also be an issue around licensing in some/all cases.

Why are you trying to do this?  To save re-installing on a new system?

Comment: Yes, but after I glance through Google, I have 2 options remained : (1) re-install OS ; (2) buy a new HDD (with larger size) and clone the old HDD to the new one. The method I suggest in the question is not quite working